# struts not populating new selected value while using jquery dialog for hidden td

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts

I have one struts html form fields( containing publish date, cutoff date) and on below those fields I have one dynamic table and the data are coming from db. And in one column of the table there is a link when I want to click the link it will open one dialog with data in same form.

I changed any value on that dialog and then close it. and then when I change the publish date it will call struts action and get the cutoff date and will show in the cutoff date field(its not ajax call). But my problem is the selected items in the modal is setting to default one after changing the publish date.

Here is my code.

```
    <script>
    function showAddr(rownum)
    {
        $("#addr"+rownum).dialog({
             title:"Edit Catalogue",
             modal: false,
             width: 980,
             zIndex: 1,
             height: 395,
             resizable:false,
             buttons: {
                 "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                     },
                "Submit":{
                    click: function(){
                        alert("Updated successfully");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    text:"Submit"
                }                
            }
        }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background","black");
    }
  </script>
    <form action="abc.do">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <logic:notEmpty property="addressList" name="AddressBean">
        <logic:iterate property="addressList" name="AddressBean"
                        scope="session" id="addressList" indexId="rownum">
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td><img id="shoAddr${rownum}" onclick="showAddr(${rownum})"></td>
        </tr>       
       <tr>
       <td colspan="3" id="addr${rownum}" style="display:none">
         <div>
         <label for="jobCodeId">City:</label>
            <html:select property="city" indexed="true" styleId="cityCodeId_${rownum}>
                <html:option value="">- Select - </html:option>
                <logic:iterate property="cityList" name="AddressBean" scope="session" id="cityCodeList">
                <c:if test='${cityCodeList.city != ""}'>
                                                        <html:option value="${cityCodeList.cityCodeId}">${cityCodeList.city}</html:option>
                                                    </c:if>
                </logic:iterate>                                    
            </html:select>
         </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      </logic:iterate>
      </logic:notEmpty>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

but if I remove display:none from the `<td>` it is showing the value what I selected after changing the publish date. Could you please help me out?

Comment: How could you show a value if it's not visible?

Comment: as you saw I am using dialog. So it should open when I click on the image.